# ¿Hay alguna forma estándar de evitar la caché del navegador cuando hay una nueva actualización de versión en la aplicación Angular?

Tags: angular, aplicación-web, cache

Tenemos Frontend Angular 13 y backend .NET Core APP alojados en uno de nuestros servidores Windows IIS.
El problema es que cada vez que hay una nueva actualización de versión, tenemos que pedirle a los usuarios que verifique la nueva versión en una pestaña de incógnito para evitar toda la caché de la versión anterior. Entonces, si podemos hacer algo desde nuestro servidor o nivel de aplicación, no necesitamos preguntarles todo el tiempo.

Tengo agregado `"output Hashing": "all"` en angular.json, pero sigue siendo igual

```
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
```

No quiero que me elimine el caché del navegador para siempre, solo necesito que el navegador del usuario se entienda que es una nueva versión

Comment: El proceso de `build` de Angular te garantiza que se despliega una versión diferente mediante el uso de `hash` en los nombres de los archivos generados. ¿Porqué tendrías que pedirle al cliente que use modo incógnito si haces el `build`? A menos que no estés haciendo el procedimiento correctamente. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa, no el cliente, es a los usuarios. He corregido la pregunta

Comment: Uso un parámetro al azar en el URL, como http://misitio/pagina?gatos=ghsh44

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando nginx para tu angular puedes agregar la cabecera Cache-Control, con esto el archivo index.html no se guardara en cache.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
       add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    }
}
```

Comment: Estoy usando IIS de Windows

Comment: En ese caso, prueba agregando esto a tu index.html

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">`

Comment: Este comando eliminará el caché del navegador para siempre, pero solo necesito que el navegador del usuario entienda que es una nueva versión

Answer (score 0):

Abajo puse una alternativa para que la revises pero la respuesta más formal es [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55517712/2658796). La traduciré aquí debajo:

Cuando hagas el build de tu aplicación angular puedes añadir el flag

```
--outputHashing=all
```

Si no lo quieres escribir siempre en el momento de buildear puedes hacer un archivo BASH que integre el flag para ahorrarte tipear y que contenga algo así como ésto o lo puedes escribir manualmente siempre:

```
ng build --prod --outputHashing=all
```

O modificar el archivo angular.json para que se vea algo así:

```
"configurations": {
"production": {
 "optimization": true,
 "outputHashing": "all",
  .
  .
  .
 }
}
```

## Alternativa para cualquier documento estático

Si sigues con problemas, puedes revisar ésta alternativa más manual que no pasa por Angular como tal. Al momento de mandar a traer en tu HTML el archivo principal de la aplicación Angular tienes algo así:

```
<script src="https://ruta.ejemplo/app.js"></script>
```

Mi recomendación es que lo llames de ésta forma

```
<script src="https://ruta.ejemplo/app.js?v=1.1657256451"></script>
```

En lugar de llamar al nombre del archivo como tal utiliza una variable GET, en éste ejemplo la variable GET `v`, para que los exploradores refresquen el contenido.

Para tu código será lo mismo pero el explorador lo considerará una ruta diferente entonces volverá a refrescar el archivo.

**Dicha variable la DEBES cambiar cada vez que hagas un lanzamiento**. La puedes dinamizar para facilitarte la labor o manualmente la cambias cada vez que hagas un lanzamiento.